# suppress blank emails

Tags: email-server, email

How do I suppress blank emails? FOr e.g. in the following example, I will like to

```
some command | mail -s "tables altered on `hostname`" me@company.com
```

I get the following message "after" sending the message:

```
Null message body; hope that's ok
```

This is not ok. I do not want to send mail if there is no text.

Comment: I am looking for an option within mail command. I do know how to check this using script.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh  

string=`some command`
len=${#string} 
if [ "$len" -gt "0" ]
   then echo $string | mail -s "tables altered on `hostname`" me@company.com
fi
```

This will send the mail only if the output of the command is at least 1 character long, but this may include blanks etc.

(The solution above works, but is unnecessary. `man mail` reveals the -E option):

```
some command | mail -E -s "tables altered on `hostname`" me@company.com
```

Comment: One liner please?

Comment: See my edit. And read the man page.

Comment: mail: invalid option -- E # I get this error message.

Comment: What OS are you on? There might be many versions of mail(x) available, Linux usually uses the BSD version. Did you check the man page to see if there are other options with that purpose? If there are not, you would need to either use my script of Jeff's reduced version of it.

Comment: for Ubuntu: ``some command | mail -e -s "tables altered on `hostname` me@company.com``

Answer (score 9):

I use the following:

```
$ mail --exec 'set nonullbody' -s Test test@example.com
```

Which I found in the [GNU mail documentation](http://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/Mail-Variables.html) under the **nullbody** section.

Comment: Ta! ... Cleanest one so far .. Especially when using cron every hour ;)

Answer (score 3):

For some implementations of `mail` the command line switch `-E` is equivalent to `--exec` which let's you execute a command. In this case [daharon's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/640187/545229) works quite well. You can even shortened it to:

```
$ mail -E 'set nonullbody' -s Test test@example.com
```

If you want to test this behavior use the `echo` command with the `-n` command line switch to suppress the trailing newline.

This command sends an email:

```
$ echo -n "something" | mail -E 'set nonullbody' -s Test test@example.com
```

But this command doesn't send an email:

```
$ echo -n "" | mail -E 'set nonullbody' -s Test test@example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

One-liner version of SvenW's answer (the creds should go to him, not me)

```
string=`some command`; [ "$len" -gt "0" ] && ( echo $string | mail -s "tables altered on `hostname`" me@company.com )
```

Comment: It seems to be missing the assignment of `$len`

Answer (score 1):

example:

echo -n "" | mail -E -s "Log Message" me@mydomain.tld

explain:

an empty string has endline character so we have to add -n to exclude in this testing echo \n (cr). But if your body message is not existing hence mail will exit/stop sending.

sources:

[Why does mail -E let me send empty messages?](https://serverfault.com/questions/611615/why-does-mail-e-let-me-send-empty-messages)
http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/mailx/mailx.1.html

Comment: You're explanation falls a bit short, mainly because you're not actually answering the original question of how to suppress blank emails. - In my humble opinion you're missing something at the start of your answer along the lines of: *"Many implementations of `mail` support the `-E` command line switch which does `<explanation of -E>` and an `example of how you would improve the original command line`* and only then your explanation of  how even `-E`  is not quite foolproof....