# Why does mail -E let me send empty messages?

Tags: centos, postfix, centos6.5, email

```
~ > which mail
/bin/mail
~ > ls -la /bin/mail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb 25 14:18 /bin/mail -> /etc/alternatives/mail
```

According to `man mail`,

> -E If an outgoing message does not contain any text in its first or only message part, do not send it but  discard  it  silently,
>   effectively  setting  the skipemptybody variable at program startup.  This is useful for sending messages from scripts started by cron(8).

However, even with `-E`, my cron script, which uses `echo`, still sends empty messages. What happens is (essentially) this:

```
logmsg=""
echo "$logmsg" | mail -E -s "Log Message" me@mydomain.tld
```

Have I misunderstood something? Why does `mail -E` send emails with empty messages?

Comment: Your empty `echo ""` is still a message, albeit one consisting of an empty line. what happens when you omit the line end with `echo -n ""` ?

Comment: echo -n prints nothing and goes to the next line in my terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Your email contains a subject so it's not empty. What happens when you try to send it without `-s "Log Message"`?

Comment: `echo "" | mail me@mydomain.tld` doesn't send an email, even without the `-E` flag.

Mail's man for `-E` says "If an outgoing message does not contain any text in its first or only message part, do not send it but  discard  it  silently." Specifically it says "part" which indicates to me that it's talking about MIME parts. Not a subject, which isn't a MIME part.

Answer (score 1):

HBruijn's comment fixed this for me - in other words:

This email was sent:

```
echo '' | mail -E -s "echo ''" root
```

but this one wasn't:

```
echo -n '' | mail -E -s "echo -n ''" root
```